# Codeigniter Insert with Select for insert_batch

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to use insert_batch with a select with codeigniter? For example I need to insert a batch of these:

```
INSERT INTO a (a_id, b_id, c_id)
    SELECT {$a}, {$b}, c.id
    FROM elci c
    WHERE c.name = {$cName}
```

Or should I just build the query string manually and execute as regular query?

Comment: im confused, why are you using a SELECT within an INSERT?

Comment: not relevant but since you asked, I'm mapping user tags to their parent table 'c' :)

Comment: Though probably did not get the full idea but this may help you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360631/how-to-insert-records-using-select-in-codeigniter-active-record

Comment: Never tried something like this before but `db->query()` just return a resource link for your query and most of the queries are acceptable. Didn't you try this query string yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$this->db->query()` or `$this->db->simple_query()` to do that, `insert_batch()` is only intended for otherwise-generated input.